# How strings and concatenation are implemented in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, performance, memory

I thought this code has bad performance:

```js
let s = '';
let ar = [];
for (let i = 0 ;i < 1e6;i++){
    s = s + String.fromCharCode(65+(i%26));
    ar.push(s);
}
console.log(ar);
console.log(ar[10000][2600]);
```

Same code in c++ will be fail, because the array "ar" will try to allocate near 10^12 byte ( 1 terabyte ) of RAM.

But it works in miliseconds in js ( console will print "and 999900 items more" ).

What is the magic behind the js strings?

Comment: it's highly repetitive work, so it gets traced/optimized by the implementation.

Comment: Why would a *reference* to an array element trigger any allocation in either JavaScript or C++?

Comment: I would suggest you to go through the below link, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/325811/memory-usage-of-javascript-string-type-with-identical-values

Comment: Well, you haven't provided the C++ code so we can't comment on it, but 1e6 is one million. Why would you need 1x10^12 bytes?

Comment: JavaScript uses UTF-16 encoding internally. So for 1e6 standard ASCII characters, each character takes 2 bytes, and it takes a total of 2*10^6 bytes (2 megabytes). Not 1*10^12 bytes.

Comment: @jarmod ar[i] will need i bytes ( or 2*i bytes ) and sum of these "i" s is 10^12

Comment: OP is storing all the intermediate strings, and reasonably expect `1+2+3+... + 1e6 ~ 1e12` characters to be stored.

Comment: I see now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic, they just use a different datastructure, a [rope](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) for example. It has better concatenation but worse indexing times.

But keep in mind that most browsers will "collapse" the strings on the first access to speed up subsequent lookups, so it will run out of memory eventually if you try to index into more of those strings.

Comment: Well, but exactly what data structure? I don't think it uses rope because of bad performance in common scenarios.

Comment: If it is collapsing strings in the first access, It does not actually need rope and some lazy concatenation works, and it seems that browsers are do this. I was expected a surprising data structure , not this :(